# Custom scroll bar visualization with HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, layout, cross-browser

I am creating a highly specialized application where I want to experiment with a custom scroll bar.

Ideally, I'd disable the built-in scroll-bar and draw my own. The page would look and feel like any other page, just that the scroll bar wouldn't be visible. The arrow keys, the scroll wheel, and any other mean of scrolling the page, should work as excepted on the platform my webapp runs on.

One way would be to put the content in a wrapper div that is absolutely positioned, with `top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;` With this approach, I would have to re-implement scrolling myself, by listening to keyboard and scroll wheel events. This is hardly ideal, especially page up and page down behavior would be hard to replicate. How many pixels should I scroll on a page down? The number varies from platform to platform. I believe magic mouse "accelerating" scrolls would be hard to replicate as well.

What are my options in implementing this custom scroll bar visualization?

**Note:** I am aware of the research that has been done regarding custom scroll bars and usability. You need not point this out, I am painfully aware of this :) I'm not talking about just re-coloring the scroll bar. Think of it more in terms of a movie editor or a music sequencer. It's very custom and specialized stuff.

**Update:** http://augustl.com/blog/2010/custom_scroll_bar_native_behaviour

Comment: ps: when you get the stuff set up and working, could you please post URL of the experiment - i would be glad to see it in action. if you  open source the event handling library + enviroment, that will be nice, too.

Comment: I'll probably extract this into a separate lib, so will do :)

Comment: Nice work on the blog post. Great to see it fully implemented.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a potential solution using javascript and css. The idea is not to remove the scrollbar but to simply hide it instead and let it keep doing it's work.

**Concept:**

Here the scrollbar of the actual content is shoved outside the wrapper. This prevents it from being seen (wrapper has `overflow:hidden;`) but does not prevent it from working.

```
|---------WRAPPER-----------|
||--------CONTENT-----------|---|
||                          |[^]|
||                          |[0]|
||                          |[0]|
||                          |[ ]|
||                          |[ ]|
||                          |[v]|
||--------------------------|---|
|---------------------------|
```

**Implementation:**

The markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>1Hello World</p>
    <p>2Hello World</p>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And the script (I've used jquery, but it could easily be rewritten in pure javascript.):

```
$(function() {
  // initialize: both need to have the same height and width (width default: 100%)
  // these could go on your stylesheet of course.
  $("div.wrapper").css({ height: "200px", overflow: "hidden" });
  $("div.content").css({ height: "200px", overflow: "auto" }); 

  // now extend the content width beyond the wrapper
  $("div.content").width($("div.content").width() + 22); // 22px is the width of IE scrollbars

  // prevent highlight dragging from scrolling the wrapper div (thereby displaying the bars)
  $("div.wrapper").scroll(function() {
    this.scrollLeft = 0;
    this.scrollTop = 0;
  });

  $("div.content").scroll(function() {
    // update custom scrollbar display using this.scrollTop as a percentage of this.clientHeight
    // alert("Place slider at " + ((100 * this.scrollTop) / this.clientHeight) + "%!");
  });
});
```

[And here it is working](http://jsbin.com/atore) (though I don't have a custom scrollbar display).

Comment: Wow, that's a really good idea! I was hoping I could keep the original scroll bar behaviour, this is kickass :)

Comment: Seems to me this could turn into an interesting jquery plugin. Just add the DOM manipulation so it could be called against `<div id="customscrolledcontent">blah blah</div>` and plenty of options for  customizing the scrollbar and you've got a winner.

Comment: nice solution, although i understand this is different what the OP asked about. i am not sure why he then checked it as the answer as no custom scrollbar is visible.

Comment: I understood the question to be asking for a method to reproduce a fully native scroll experience with custom scrollbars. This is that method without the scrollbars, though those are easy to add.

Comment: Indeed - I asked how I could have the behaviour of a native scrollbar with no native scroll bar visible.

Comment: wow ... that's great ... i wonder if anybody out there managed already to add a custom scrollbar to this solution. thanks anyway for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

I guess since this is highly specialized thing, there is no need to talk about usability :-)

The only thing I am aware of is to implement your own event capture - based on keypress, mousedown etc. - it should be easy to get the current position of page (kind of virtual - because you will have everything loaded and just change the custom "viewport").

I highly recommend checking great QuirksMode tutorials and docs:

- Keypress events: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html
- Mouse events: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

I am not sure about scrolling wheel, though - I haven't heard about technique to emulate that, but surely you would be able to find or code something.

EDIT: I have found some low-level JS implementation of scroll wheel (click wheel):
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-the-scroll-wheel

Comment: There are events for scroll wheel usage. A bigger problem would be to replicate page up and page down, and have them scroll the same amount that the default page up and page down would scroll..

Comment: Actually, he could disable pageup/pagedown events by doing `return false` in the function where he checks for the key press. also, i think, the movement in pixels is not a problem for him - as he basically needs only to have the event captured - no need to simulate the actual pageup/pagedown movement.