# Custom Scrollbar with jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

I'm already using jQuery to customize my select boxes, but recently i've noticed in one of the drop-downs that the list is really huge.

So I wonder how it's possible to style scrollbar with CSS3 + jQuery. I would like to apply that style to all scrollbars on my page or do you think it would be better to apply it to only  elements?

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done with CSS alone. Scrollbar styling is not supported by any browsers except IE.

In order to create a custom scrollbar style you must either fake the scroll bar (see [Custom scroll bar visualization with HTML/CSS/JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254585/custom-scroll-bar-visualization-with-html-css-javascript/2278083#2278083)) or use a javascript library that does all the work for you (like a jquery plugin).

Several jquery plugins are listed here: http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: It can't be done with CSS. You either use a javascript library (jquery or otherwise) or roll your own javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will needhttp://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

A very nice scrollbar plugin

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions. I've checked all those plugins already.