# custom scrollbar for custom jquery ui combobox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, scrollbar

I've been working on a combobox widget for awhile and it's working like I need it too... so now I want to make it look better and one thing I'd like is to change the look of the scrollbar. I've tried pretty much everything that a search could find with no luck. These 2 seemed to be the most promising, easy to implement...

[custom scrollbar 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254585/custom-scroll-bar-visualization-with-html-css-javascript/2278083#2278083)

[custom scrollbar 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254585/custom-scroll-bar-visualization-with-html-css-javascript/2278083#2278083)

I have managed to detect the mouse wheel within the drop down list but can't get the list to scroll or add a visible scrollbar... here's the code...

EDIT: Here's the updated code that works to scroll the menu list... just need to figure out how to add a scrollbar...

```
"wheel .ui-menu":function(event){
    var scrollTopEle=this.uiMenu.scrollTop();

    if (event.originalEvent.deltaY < 0){
      this.uiMenu.scrollTop(scrollTopEle-20);
    }else{
      this.uiMenu.scrollTop(scrollTopEle+20);
    }
    return false;       
},
```

also had to change the css  `overflow-y: auto;` to `overflow-y: hidden;`

And here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frankn/pf8r3qsg/85/) to the widget... please keep in mind this is my first widget but feel free to comment or give suggestions on improvements or mistakes... rip my code!

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I did to get this working... might not be the best solution but it gets the job done...

CSS...

```
.ui-combobox .ui-autocomplete{
    max-height: 1000px; 
    overflow-x: hidden; /* horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-y: hidden; /* vertical scrollbar */
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

JS...

```
"wheel .ui-menu":function(event){
    var scrollTopMenu=this.uiMenu.scrollTop(),
scrollHeight=Math.round(this.menuItemHeight);

if (event.originalEvent.deltaY<0){
    this.uiMenu.scrollTop(scrollTopMenu-scrollHeight);
}else{
    this.uiMenu.scrollTop(scrollTopMenu+scrollHeight);
}

return false;
},
```

How I get `this.menuItemHeight`...

```
uiMenuItemLineHeight=parseFloat($('.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a').css('line-height')),
uiMenuItemPadding=parseFloat($('.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a').css('padding-top')),
uiMenuItemTopBorder=parseFloat($uiMenu.css('border-top-width')),
uiMenuItemBtmBorder=parseFloat($uiMenu.css('border-bottom-width')),
menuItemHeight=uiMenuItemLineHeight+uiMenuItemPadding+uiMenuItemTopBorder+uiMenuItemBtmBorder, menuUserHeight=menuUserItems*menuItemHeight,
```

So now I can scroll without a problem... but I still don't have a scrollbar which sucks because users can't tell if there's more items in the list than visible... so I came up with this solution... what I do is check to see if the menu is longer than the drop down, if it is I just style the cursor to a different cursor style to le the user know that the field can be scrolled... I'll eventually make a custom cursor that will be more representative of being able to scroll.

```
if(menuElementHeight>menuHeight){
    $uiMenu.css('cursor', 'context-menu');
}
```

I'll keep working at getting a scrollbar in there but for now this works for me and hopefully it can help someone out.

Here's a link to the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frankn/pf8r3qsg/155/)